# Is this sql query vulnerable to injection?

Tags: php, mysql, code-injection

```
$column = $_GET['id'];
$result = mysql_query("SELECT $column FROM table");
echo $result;
```

I'm building a website with mysql and am thus trying to learn about sql injections. I assume that this code is vulnerable, but i cant seem to make a working exploit. How would i pull column 'here' from table 'example2'?

Thanks

Comment: It is very vulnerable. Try to use mysql_real_escape_string and sanitize your variables (if $_GET['id'] is an integer do $id=(int)$_GET['id'])

Comment: Suggesting `mysql_real_escape_string_for_real_this_time` is hardly better than the original. It's 2011. Use prepared statements.

Answer (score 6):

Imagine $_GET['id'] was equal to something like this

```
* FROM anytable_i_want; --
```

the double hypen means the rest of your string is a comment ... so now the sql you're executing is:

```
SELECT * FROM anytable_i_want;
```

The single best way to protect from this kind of nonsense is the prepared statement. If you use, say the PDO interface, you do something like this:

```
$HANDLE = $PDO->prepare('SELECT ? FROM mytable');
$HANDLE->execute(array($_GET['id']));
```

now no matter what was submitted as $_GET['id'] it woudlnt have any odd effects.

`mysql_real_escape_string` will cover you if using my mysql_ family of functions, although there is an exploit in the wild that you may be subject to if you change the charset at runtime.

Comment: Excellent non-multiple query (ie, applicable) example of the risk! +1

Comment: Thanks a lot man, I didn't know that I could comment the rest of the query with a double hyphen.

Comment: the mysql_ family of function are old and really shouldn't be used. It's been superceeded by mysqli_ and PDO, both of which allow for prepared statements. I personally prefer PDO but you should choose one of those two if you're working in PHP.

Comment: +1 For right away not jumping on `mysql_real_escape_string` (almost +0 for not adding a strong disclaimer though). However, prepared statements can be used with "just" [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) -- e.g. doesn't require PDO.

Comment: I tend to evangelize PDO over mysqli; I find the later clunky and difficult to use.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at PDO and the use of prepared statements to help with preventing SQL injections:

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/

Answer (score 1):

make $column something like :

```
" here FROM example2 -- "
```

Comment: `mysql_query` doesn't allow multiple queries, so this would just throw an error.

Answer (score 1):

if the following text was passed as $_GET['id'], you would have an exploit:

`$_GET['id'] = '[other sql commands here]';`

use either `mysql_real_escape_string()` or `mysqli_real_escape_string()` (if you are using the improved interface)

Comment: @yc I guess you can tell I'm not a sql injection hacker :-)